# Let me know when the official time and date of the meeting are/is?

Tags: grammaticality, time, sentence-ends

Which is the correct sentence?

Let me know when the official time and date of the meeting **are** when determined and I will be there!

Let me know when the official time and date of the meeting **is** when determined and I will be there!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. When asking questions about "correctness," it is best to indicate which *you* think is correct, and why you are confused. The short answer is that either may be correct, depending on whether you consider *time and date* to be one set of things, or two separate things. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: The most usual way to ask this is to leave out the verb which is giving you the problem altogether and say "Let me know the time and date of the meeting"